# Unit Testing iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing

How can I implement an unit test for iOS? My app just has text fields and POSTS and GETS data with RESTful webservices

Are there any good beginner guides for this? 
Is unit testing really essential for app development?

Comment: Probably you can take a look first at the general concept of Testing and why we test. Maybe later you can dive into Unit Testing and how having a set of good Unit Tests in your project can be beneficial for the product you are developing. Later on probably you might check your self how to write some basics Unit Tests and if you are struggling with issues in one of them you may post some code here to show us what you have trying to do and what problem you are facing in your code. That will help a lot I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use XCTest. Apple has been encouraging unit testing more and more. Now every project includes a testing target that is specifically for unit testing, and Xcode has nice unit testing features. You can check out the Testing in Xcode 5 video at the 2013 WWDC [here.](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't messed with unit testing in iOS. I thought you just wanted to learn about Unit Testing on iOS. The iOS development community has been slow to adopt unit testing. Maybe they talk about that in the WWDC video.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OCMock to stub the part of your code that is performing the POSTSs and GETS and their corresponding responses.

The mock stub can act like the server, it can receive the POSTS/GETS and respond just as the real webservice would (the mock object could inject real responses that you have previously captured while running against the webservice).

http://ocmock.org